# How can I run a python-rq rqworker as an attached-daemon in UWSGI in python 3 without ASCII encoding errors?

Tags: python-3.x, locale, uwsgi, python-rq

I'm trying to run rqworker as an attached-daemon in UWSGI. To do this I add to the config.ini file:

```
attach-daemon = /path/to/rqworker
```

Then UWSGI tries to launch rqworker when it should but I get the following error in the logs:

> RuntimeError: Click will abort further execution because Python 3 was
>   configured to use ASCII as encoding for the environment. Either switch
>   to Python 2 or consult http://click.pocoo.org/python3/ for mitigation
>   steps.

I can run rqworker fine from bash but the encoding seems to be not set correctly for the daemon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the linked page in that message:

> You are dealing with an environment where Python 3 thinks you are
>   restricted to ASCII data. The solution to these problems is different
>   depending on which locale your computer is running in.
>
> For instance, if you have a German Linux machine, you can fix the
>   problem by exporting the locale to de_DE.utf-8:
>
> export LC_ALL=de_DE.utf-8 export LANG=de_DE.utf-8 If you are on a US
>   machine, en_US.utf-8 is the encoding of choice. On some newer Linux
>   systems, you could also try C.UTF-8 as the locale:
>
> export LC_ALL=C.UTF-8 export LANG=C.UTF-8

To set the encoding in the UWSGI config.ini file you can use "env" to set environment variables and in turn the locale. On a US machine this configuration would work:

```
env = LC_ALL=en_US.utf-8
env = LANG=en_US.utf-8
attach-daemon = /path/to/rqworker
```

On other machines, various other encodings could be used.